# Create class with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript

I create a class for my RPG games, and I would like to ask the user the name of their character, how can I do this ?

Pitch is the base name I created, but I would like pitch to be replaced by the name given by the user

```js
class Personnage {
  constructor(nom, sante, force) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.sante = sante;
    this.force = force;
    this.xp = 0; 
  }
  
  const principal = new Personnage("Pitch", 150, 25);
```

Thx for your answers ! (sorry for my english aha)

Comment: at all the down voters, we were all new at one point guys

Comment: Thanks Stephen...

Answer (score -1):

Consider this version to achieve what you are trying.

```
    class Personnage {
     var _nom;
     var _force;
     var _xp;
  constructor(nom, sante, force) {
    _nom = nom;
    _sante = sante;
    _force = force;
    _xp = 0; 
  }

  const principal = new Personnage(some_user_variable, 150, 25);
```

Though it is unclear what you are trying to do.  Does this help?

Comment: Thx for your answer ! It's helping me ! And what do i put in place of "Pitch" ?

Comment: I assume somewhere else in the code you have a variable containing the user's name.  I will edit the answer with this assumption

Comment: so when calling the constructor pass in the variable you want with the users name instead of "Pitch".

Comment: "I think using const is a mistake" — They aren't. "consider let or var instead." — Your code throws syntax errors.

Comment: @StephenFlynn yes

Comment: @Draags best of luck, if you have any questions please ask. I will answer when i can.

Comment: I can't create var, it makes me mistakes "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Comment: that was my mistake, you should use const.